# Scrapy Shell: twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost although USER_AGENT is set

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

When I try to scrape a certain web site (with both, spider and shell), I get the following error:

```
twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion.>]
```

I found out that this can happen, when no user agent is set.
But after setting it manually, I still got the same error.

You can see the whole output of scrapy shell here: http://pastebin.com/ZFJZ2UXe

### Notes:

I am not behind a proxy, and I can access other sites via scrapy shell without problems. I am also able to access the site with Chrome, so it is not a network or connection issue.

Maybe someone can give me a hint how I could solve this problem?

Comment: So whats the issue? Just set `user-agent` and continue your scraping... the remote website might be set not to respond to any request without any `user-agent` in it

Comment: As I said, I get the same error when I set the user-agent .. and I have no idea where to look next. I will edit the answer so it may be better understandable. (also, if you look into the pastebin link, you can see, that I set a user-agent)

Comment: See my answer ... you must send `headers` along with request.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is 100% working code.

What you need to do is you have to send request headers as well.

Also set `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False` in `settings.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy, logging
from scrapy.http.request import Request

class Test1SpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test1_spider"

    def start_requests(self):

        headers = {
            "Host": "www.firmenabc.at",
            "Connection": "keep-alive",
            "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
            "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36",
            "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
            "DNT": "1",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch",
            "Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.8"
        }

        yield Request(url= 'http://www.firmenabc.at/result.aspx?what=&where=Graz', callback=self.parse_detail_page, headers=headers)

    def parse_detail_page(self, response):
        logging.info(response.body)
```

**EDIT:**

You can see what headers to send by inspecting the URLs in Dev Tools

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know about the headers. Just for future issues: Is there a way how to find out which header information I have to send?

Comment: @areiterer see my edited answer, also please upvote my answer

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, unfortunately I'm not allowed to upvote answers yet, sorry!